# Cross compile: why ld searching for x86_64 and not mipsel?

Tags: cross-compiling, ld

I want to cross compile extundelete for mipsel.
Host is x86_64 slackware.
I use this [build](https://pastebin.com/86kXpcex)
The error is

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/5.5.0/../../../../x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /opt/e2fsprogs-mipsel/lib//libcom_err.so when searching for -lcom_err
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/5.5.0/../../../../x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld: extundelete-block.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 8)
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/5.5.0/../../../../x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld: extundelete-block.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 8)
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/5.5.0/../../../../x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld: extundelete-block.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 8)
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/5.5.0/../../../../x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld: extundelete-block.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 8)
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/5.5.0/../../../../x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld: extundelete-block.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 8)
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/5.5.0/../../../../x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld: extundelete-block.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 8)
```

I have passed LD flags why is using the x86_64 ld?
Some error on flags or what?
If I remove the lcomm_err part cannot find the ext* libs.

Comment: Do you get the errors when building the cross environment, or when building your application? If you're building your own application, do you use the cross `ld`?

Comment: When building the application, and using the cross ld with export LD=/path

Comment: Please edit the question to give us more context, for example the *exact* commands you use. How do you set up `CC`? How do you set up `LD`? How do you build the application?

Comment: I have post the pastebin link, if I post the entire code the site don't allow me to put it because "mainly code" https://pastebin.com/86kXpcex